# Android crashing with "couldn't find key level in dynamic object" in RN 0.59.10

Tags: react-native

The app crashes immediately after launching with an uncaught exception saying the following:

> couldn't find key level in dynamic object

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was providing a SectionList a contentInset, which is a property only available for iOS.

The solution was to not pass that prop on Android, like so:

```
contentInset={Platform.select({ ios: { bottom: 60 } })}
```